# Bootstrap div vertical allign in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

row div on my page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter time-incoming"> <span>sent 9 days ago</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="bubble bubble--alt"> <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to achieve that my "sent 9 days ago" span would be vertical-aligned but `display: table` and `vertical-align` didn't help me.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NickBunich/aYNgH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to apply the `display:table-cell` to an element, you have to set its ancestor to be `display:table`. In other word, the only following won't work:

```
.vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

So, I added the following code to make it works:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    display: table;
}
```

Then, add the `.wrapper` class to the parent of `.vcenter`:

```
<div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter time-incoming"> 
        <span>sent 9 days ago</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
When you expand the window size more than `992px`, `Twitter Bootstrap` put the `float:left` for you:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
float: left;
}
```

That why the `span` text turned back to the top. You can remove the `float:left` by setting it into `none`:

```
.vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:none
}
```

See the modified [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvarayut/aYNgH/5/)

Comment: but if you stretch it harder it'll return back on top

Comment: I opened it using Chrome. It works perfectly, it's never returned back on top.

Comment: This resolution works - http://yadi.sk/d/OEAkZ2D3QHzEK this resolution - doesn't work http://yadi.sk/d/2ixmAPZ_QHytp